# Enterキーで次のtextaeraに、Backspaceキーで前のtextareaにfocusを移したいです

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

タイトルの通りです。質問させてください。EnterキーとBackspaceキーでのfocusの移動に対応した、textareaのディレクティブをつくっています。
textareaで入力したあと、Enterキーを押すとitemを保存して次のelementにfocusを移動、texttareaが空のときのみBackspaceキーを押すとitemを保存して前のelementにfocusを移動させる、ということをさせたいのですが詰まってしまって困っています... 見づらいコードですみませんがよろしくお願いいたします。

### view(slim):

```
ul.section-list ng-repeat="content in shop.contents"
  li.section ng-repeat="item in content.items"
    div
      textarea name="body" my-directive="" ng-model="item.body" ng-blur="itemSave(shop, content, item)"
```

### javascript(angular):

```
angular.module('myDirective', []).directive 'myDirective', ->
  {
    restrict: 'A'
    require: '?ngModel'
    link: (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) ->
      el = angular.element(element[0])

      el.on 'keypress', (e) ->
        if e.keyCode == 13  #Enterキーが押されたとき
          el.blur()
          # Enterキーで確定して次の要素に移りたい...
          angular.element(element[0+1]).focus()  #error
          return
        return

      el.on 'keydown', (e) ->
        if e.keyCode == 8  #Backspaceキーが押されたとき
          if scope.content.items[scope.$index].body == ''  #textareaが空のとき
            el.blur()
            # Backspaceキー確定して前の要素に移りたい...
            angular.element(element[0]).focus()  #error
            return
          return
        return
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

ディレクティブを並列操作する時は親となるディレクティブを用意するとうまくいきます。
https://jsfiddle.net/4c1t7v42/

ちなみに、`link()`の第2引数は`angular.element`オブジェクトですので、
`var el = angular.element(elem[0]);`
のような処理は不要です。

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('AppController', function() {
  this.items = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'];
})
.directive('parent', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    transclude: true,
    template: '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>',
    scope: {
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
      var children = [];
      this.addChild = function(elem) {
        children.push(elem);
      };
      this.removeChild = function(elem) {
        var index = children.indexOf(elem);
        if (index !== -1) {
          children.splice(index, 1);
        }
      }
      this.next = function(elem) {
        var index = children.indexOf(elem);
        if (index !== -1) {
          children[(index + 1) % children.length].focus();
        }
      };
      this.prev = function(elem) {
        var index = children.indexOf(elem);
        if (index !== -1) {
          children[(index + children.length - 1) % children.length].focus();
        }
      };
    },
  };
})
.directive('child', function() {
  function save(elem) {
    // データ保存のためのコード
  }

  return {
    require: '^^parent',
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
    },
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs, parent) {
      parent.addChild(elem);
      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        parent.removeChild(elem);
      });
      elem.on('keypress', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 13){
          save(elem);
          parent.next(elem);
          return false;
        }
      });
      elem.on('keydown', function(e) {
        if(e.keyCode === 8 && elem.val().length === 0) {
          save(elem);
          parent.prev(elem);
          return false;
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController as app">
  <ul parent>
    <li ng-repeat="item in app.items">
      <textarea child ng-model="item" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。一番最後のtextareaでEnterを押したときに先頭に移動しない and 一番最初のtextareaでBackspaceを押したときに後尾に移動しない、シンプルなものを想定しているのですがもう少し簡単に書くことはできませんでしょうか？

Comment: `parent`ディレクティブを使わないとしたらこういう感じでしょうか。http://jsfiddle.net/LbusLfq4/ 要素をjQueryセレクタで拾ってくる部分が心もとないので、私は全体管理用のディレクティブを置く方を好みますが。

Comment: 何度もすみません... 最初にいただいたサンプルコードで、一番最後のtextareaでEnterを押したときに先頭に移動しないかる一番最初のtextareaでBackspaceを押したときに後尾に移動しないものをつくっているのですが思い通りに動きません... 再度こちらのサンプルをいただきたいです

Comment: `this.prev()`と`this.next()`をほんの少し書き換えるだけです https://jsfiddle.net/jgL5mabr/